# Correct mapping to interface when getting data from a given URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, single-page-application

I am new to Angular and I am trying to map the returned `json` to my interface but failed.

Here's the link to the code I have.

- [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-get)
- [Json URL](https://api.myjson.com/bins/11x4bx)

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to use map since you response is object and as i see you want to map data property from that.

One way to do it would be

```
  getTestData(): Observable<TestObject>{
    const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/11x4bx';

    // return this.http.get(url).pipe(
    //   map(response => ((response || {} as any).data || []).map(testData => this.mapTest(testData))));


    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map((resp: any) => {
          return <TestObject> {
            id: resp.data.id,
            view: resp.data.view,
            resourceName: resp.data.resourcename,
            loadCapacity: resp.data.loadcapacity
          }
      })
      );


  }
```

Cleaner way

```
  getTestData(): Observable<TestObject>{
    const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/11x4bx';
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(pluck('data'));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll check 'pluck'.

Answer (score 1):

When you are not sure about how to build an interface for your response, you can use **[JSON2TS](http://json2ts.com/)**

```
declare module namespace {

    export interface Meta {
        entityName: string;
    }

    export interface Data {
        id: string;
        view: string;
        startdate: string;
        enddate: string;
        erp: string;
        loadcapacity: string;
        userid: string;
        resourceid: string;
        resourcename: string;
        userdatalimitationid: string;
        requestleaveforself: boolean;
        bookforself: boolean;
        lastmodified: string;
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        meta: Meta;
        data: Data;
    }

}
```

Comment: this is not a correct answer. Doesn't fix his issue

Comment: yes.  I dont understand why this answer is related.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should change your code. You should use map when your data is an array. Your response data is just an object

```
 getTestData(): Observable<TestObject>{
    const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/11x4bx';

    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        console.log(res)
          return {
            id: res.data.id,
            view: res.data.view,
            resourceName: res.data.resourcename,
            loadCapacity: res.data.loadcapacity
          } as TestObject
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use map twice.

The first **map** from **RxJS** is to do data transformation. In this case you are sending through the pipe an Object, not an array. So you don't need  to use the second **map** since that's a method to iterate through an array.

```
 return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map((resp: any) => 
           ({
            id: resp.data.id,
            view: resp.data.view,
            resourceName: resp.data.resourcename,
            loadCapacity: resp.data.loadcapacity
          }) as TestObject)
      );

  }
```

Your wiki:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-get-1dg2r2

FYI in reactive programming is better to do the Declarative approach

wait, what is that?

```
testObject$ = this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map((resp: any) => 
           ({
            id: resp.data.id,
            view: resp.data.view,
            resourceName: resp.data.resourcename,
            loadCapacity: resp.data.loadcapacity
          }) as TestObject)
      );

  }
```

then in your component you call it `testService.testObject$`

You see what I did I got rid of the method and here's why:

1. -Leverage the power of rxjs observables and opeartors
2. -effectively compatible streams
3. -easy share observables
4. -readily react to user action

@Deborah Kurata mentioned this in his RxJS course (she is a GDE on Angular)